# Computing $\lim_{x→\infty}\ln(3x ^2 − 4x + 2) − \ln(5x ^2 + 19x − 1)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I've been having troubles with limits, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try $\log(a)-\log(b)=\log(\frac a b)$ and analyse the behaviour of $\frac a b$ first.

Comment: Please put the question in the text

Comment: Calculate the following limit: limx→∞ ln(3x ^2 − 4x + 2) − ln(5x ^2 + 19x − 1) =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the $\ln$ property: $\ln(a)-\ln(b)=\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{3x^2-4x+2}{5x^2+19x-1}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{3-\frac{4}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}{5+\frac{19}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)$$

$\ln$ is continuous, so we can swap $\lim$ and $\ln$:

$$\ln\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{3-\frac{4}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}{5+\frac{19}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)$$

Comment: The "swapping" of $\ln$ and $\lim$ is only allowed if the resulting limit converges, not just because $\ln$ is continuous!

Answer (score 0):

Since logarithmic functions are continuous we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln(3x^2-4x+2)-\ln(5x^2+19x-1)&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{3x^2-4x+2}{5x^2+19x-1}\right)\\
&=\ln\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x^2-4x+2}{5x^2+19x-1}\right)
\end{align}